# Something is wrong with my inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm practicing Java inheritance this week. My task is to design a small program that calculate the employee's annual salaries. The task requires me to:

- Make the class Employee implements the interface Taxes.
- Define the method getGrossSalary() within Employee class. Assume that the gross salary is equal to the following equation: Base salary + Time employed bonus (Base salary = $40000/year)
  Time employed bonus = $1000/year employed
- Define the method getNetSalary() within Employee class. Assume that the net salary is equal to the following equation: Gross salary - (Gross salary * Tax rate)
- Tax rate should be obtained by invoking the getTaxRate() static method located within the interface Taxes.
- Create a child class Manager that inherits from the class Employee. Override the method getBonus() so that each manager gets an extra $10000 additional to the time employed bonus.

Everything is okay, but when I tried to make Manager inherit its superclass Employee, the program got error! I couldn't fix it even I tried to find out the problem on the Internet, or asked some of my friends.

Here is my Employee.java code:

```
public class Employee implements Taxes {
private double baseSalary = 40000;
int years;
private double grossSalary;
private double netSalary;

public Employee(int years) {
    this.years = years;
}

public double getGrossSalary() {
    grossSalary = baseSalary + getBonus();
    return grossSalary;
}

public double getNetSalary() {
    netSalary = grossSalary - grossSalary * getTaxRate(grossSalary);
    return netSalary;
}

public double getBonus() {
    return years*1000;
}

public static double getTaxRate(double grossSalary) {
    if (grossSalary < 10000 ) {
        return 0.05;
    } else if (grossSalary >= 10000 && grossSalary < 20000) {
        return 0.07;
    } else if (grossSalary >= 20000 && grossSalary < 50000) {
        return 0.10;
    } else {
        return 0.15;
    }
}
}
```

And here is my Manager.java code, which occurs the error "constructor Employee in class Employee cannot be applied to given types" :

```
public class Manager extends Employee {
public Manager( int years ) {
    this.years = years;
}

public double getBonus() {
    return years*10000;
}
}
```

Comment: Who gave you this task?

Comment: I have this task on edx.org , Lesson 2 of Java Fundamentals for Android Development

Comment: As I read it the manager getBonus method should work as this: return super.getBonus() + 10000;

Comment: @M.Schwarzer-Haverbier Oops.....
Thank you very much for your attention! I suffered two days wondering why my code didn't return the result as the test presented <3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the constructor of class `Manager`, you must make sure that the appropriate constructor of its superclass `Employee` is called. You can do that by using `super(...)`:

```
public Manager(int years) {
    super(years);
}
```

If you don't specify this, Java is going to try to call the constructor of class `Employee` that takes no parameters. Since class `Employee` does not have a constructor that takes no parameters, this will fail, as you have noticed.

See: [Using the Keyword `super`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) in Oracle's Java Tutorials.

Comment: Nice (y) I made it!

Comment: So, when I make a class inherit from another class, I'll have to super(its parameters), right?

Comment: Anyway, thanks a lot for your help, sir! <3

Answer (score 0):

The super constructor must be invoked in each constructor of your class (or another constructor of your class via `this(...)`). If you don't call a specific constructor, the compiler adds the default one.
But there is no default `Employee()` construcor so you get the error. Change your `Manager` constructor to

```
public Manager( int years ) {
    super(years);
    this.years = years; // not needed because Employee has this field as well
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do specify a constructor explicitly (as in Employee with parameter) the Java compiler will not create a parameterless constructor for you. So you need to explicitly call the base class constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions:

1- make a default constructor on your Employee class, Because if you don't specify a constructor in the subclass compiler will search for the default one and It doesn't exist.

```
public Employee() {

}
```

2- or you could call the custom constructor you have in the super class:

```
public Manager(int years) {
    super(years);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not that much java guy but you have no default constructor on Employee class, how is supossed to init base class?

By what i know on Manager constructor you should have something like

```
public Manager(int years){ 
    super(years); 
}
```